# What is a more expedient way to assign variable names to individual elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, associations, refactoring

There is a set of one-dimensional descriptive statistics that I need so often that instead of copying and pasting calculations each time I created a function (`generateStatsX[...]`) that returns all values in a single list into a second function (`statisticalAnalysis[...]`). But now I am left having to reassign a name (a variable) to each value so I could use them in further calculations. The code below works but I feel it could be done more expediently within function `statisticalAnalysis[...]`. Is there better way to code this? Please note that I am looking for a solution that does not pollute the Global space.

```
generateStatsX[raw_, bias_ : Infinity, declen_ : 2] := 
 Block[{len, n, range, midrange, μ, median, mode, σavg, 
   rms, σ2, σ, Em, Es, skew, kurt, mean},
  {len = Length[raw],(* true length of raw data *)
   n = If[len <= bias, len - 1, len, len - 1],(* 
   adjusted length removes bias in variance if n ≤ 
   bias cutoff *)
   range = Max[raw] - Min[raw],
   midrange = Min[raw] + range/2,
   μ = Mean[raw],
   median = Median[raw],
   mode = Commonest[raw][[1]],
   σavg = Sum[Abs[raw[[x]] - μ], {x, 1, len}]/len,
   rms = Sqrt[Sum[(raw[[x]] - μ)^2, {x, 1, len}]/len],
   σ2 = Total[(raw - μ)^2]/n, (* variance *)
   σ = Sqrt[σ2],(* standard deviation *)
   Es = .6745 σ,(* 
   error for single x with 50% of data within 1 std deviation *)
   Em = Es/Sqrt[n],(* standard error of the mean *)
   skew = Skewness[raw],
   kurt = Kurtosis[raw],
   mean = 
    ToString[NumberForm [μ, {Infinity, declen}]] <> 
     " ± " <> ToString[NumberForm[Em, {Infinity, declen}]]}
  ]
statisticalAnalysis[raw_] := Block[{stats, vars},
  stats = generateStatsX[raw];
  vars = {len = stats[[1]], n = stats[[2]], range = stats[[3]], 
    midrange = stats[[4]], μ = stats[[5]], median = stats[[6]], 
    mode = stats[[7]], σavg = stats[[8]], 
    rms = stats[[9]], σ2 = stats[[10]], σ = stats[[11]],
     Em = stats[[12]], Es = stats[[13]], skew = stats[[14]], 
    kurt = stats[[15]], mean = stats[[16]]};
  Row[{len, n, range}, "  |  "] (* 
  demo first 3 variables as proof of concept *)
  ]
statisticalAnalysis[{1.32, 1.37, 1.43, 1.32, 1.36, 1.33, 1.38, 1.35, 
  1.48, 1.28, 1.31, 1.52, 1.51, 1.33, 1.32, 1.27, 1.35, 1.40, 1.27, 
  1.39, 1.50, 1.31, 1.34, 1.48, 1.36, 1.33, 1.40, 1.29, 1.35, 1.36, 
  1.33, 1.30, 1.28, 1.32, 1.34, 1.33, 1.29, 1.34, 1.34, 1.29, 1.35, 
  1.52, 1.29, 1.38, 1.40, 1.28, 1.36, 1.36, 1.32, 1.62, 1.36, 1.34, 
  1.33, 1.33, 1.30, 1.31, 1.33, 1.32, 1.36, 1.41}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have names of variables, and have list of values and want to assign variables to values?

In this case, one way could be

```
Clear["Global`*"];
values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
vars = {len, n, range, midrange, μ, median, mode, σavg, 
                 rms, σ2, σ, Em, Es, skew, kurt, mean};
```

Then do

```
 MapThread[Set, {vars, values}]
```

Now they are assigned.

Comment: thank you so much. you came through for ne again.  it works beautifully and such an elegant solution.

Comment: Also `Evaluate[vars] = values`.

Comment: I really wish there was something like `ScanThread[]`...